# iOS EventKit - Event is not being deleted from calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I'm deleting event using the following code

```
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        EKEvent *event = [store eventWithIdentifier:eventIdentifier];
        NSError *eventDeleteError = nil;
        if (event) {
            [store removeEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&eventDeleteError];
        }

        if (eventDeleteError) {
            NSLog(@"Event Deletion Error: %@", eventDeleteError);
        }

}];
```

I got no error in `eventDeleteError` but following message appear in the console log

> `CADObjectGetInlineStringProperty` failed fetching UUID for `EKPersistentAttendee` with error `Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 "`The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1010.)"

Answer (score 4):

I was getting similar error on removing a calendar:

> CADObjectGetIntProperty failed with error Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1010.)"
>   CADObjectGetRelation failed with error Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1010.)"

As it is not exactly the same message I will just explain what helped me.
The issue came from making "remove" operation on a new EventStore object. Try to make sure you hold a reference to EventStore and both adding and removing operations are called on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error several times and it's always because my `eventIdentifier` is bad and there is no matching record for my `eventIdentifier`. Always my code has been at fault.