# DJI developer connecting error

Tags: dji-sdk

please check below error i m getting this error when i run GEO System Application example code provide by DJI developer i m not able to connect my app to their sdk.

i have already change my app key into code and its registering successfully but showing error when i start and stop mission..

Error Domain=DJISDKErrorDomain Code=-1010 "There was an error connecting to the SDK.(code:-1010)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There was an error connecting to the SDK.(code:-1010)}

Answer (score 0):

**Info:** Most probably you are running the app in the XCode simulator. The problem is that your app is not connected to the drone.

**Solution:** Deploy the app on an iOS device and connect it to the DJI product (drone or handheld).

**Hint:** To test the app you can use the flight simulator applications developed by DJI. Just check [this website](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-testing.html) to download the appropriate program for your drone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not likely to be DJI related but permission or setting missing. Try this one with another app that has same error code:
[iOS EventKit - Event is not being deleted from calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215343/ios-eventkit-event-is-not-being-deleted-from-calendar)